# Firefox folder has a weird name on Manjaro/Arch

Tags: linux, arch-linux, firefox, manjaro

So I wanted to know where firefox keeps my history.

I did `find . | grep firefox` and I found:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/wirlzfux.default
```

I can't seem to find anything on google or github about why this directory might be called that and it's got me real spooked.

I'm on manjaro linux. Have I been pwned ?

Comment: A random name is always used. Example : `.mozilla/firefox/8t5sc91o.default-1511624768189`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always has a weird name, on my Windows system it is:

```
C:\Users\ME\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ga3z13xy.default-release
```

This is the default profile folder firefox creates. You can always start up firefox's profile manager by the following command to delete that profile and create a new one in whichever folder you like:

```
firefox -p
```

[image]